# adding same style sheet to many html files

Tags: html, css

I have created a very small personal website with three different pages and one CSS file. I know to embed a CSS file into an html page is the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css"/>
```

but form some reason the CSS file only work in  one page. Any advice please

Comment: have you added that code to all the html pages?

Comment: yeah i have added the code to all the html pages

Comment: I have tried before, all files are in the same folder

Answer (score 1):

Did you checked your folders structure? You may have other html file in different folders.

I suggest to use an absolute path for your stylesheet. something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/mystyle.css"/>
```

first / in href parameter is what I mean.

Edit: You may use a windows machine and upload your files into a Linux machine. Windows do not care about lowercase or uppercase, but it is important on Linux. rename all your filenames to lowercase every where and use it exactly the same in your code (check your link tags again). this may fix your problem

Comment: all my files are located in the same folder, its very strange because it works properly offline, but as soon as uploaded the files to the web it doesn't work

Comment: I add something to my answer, check that again

Comment: That's normally referred to as *root* relative (leading slash).

Comment: @steveax yes, that is what I mean. Thanks for remark

Comment: If you are fine on local, but there are issues on production I might suggest checking file permissions on the server.  Also might not hurt to load an affected page in a browser, view source and also try to get to the css file directly through the browser.  ie.. www.thewebsite.com/css/mystyle.css  (changing the url) and see if the css file loads.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the link of the site would be helpful. Make sure that the line of CSS aboves goes on each page. For example, if you have 3 pages with 3 different files: index.htm, bio.htm and contact.htm (I'm having to guess since I have not gotten this info from you). Then make sure the link to the CSS above appears on each of those pages.

Comment: yeah every single html files has the link to the CSS file, offline works but as soon as upload my files to the web it doesn't